# Pandas GroupBy object to dataframe, store data in a comma separated file

Tags: python, pandas

```
interactions_df = interactions[interactions['interaction_type'].isin([1,2,3])]
```

I have interaction_df dataframe. Which when printed appears as:

```
user_id item_id interaction_type    created_at
1974005 2668706 1   1444154047
2690450 405777  1   1445338496
2690450 1180447 1   1444806365
2690450 1803133 1   1440480562
2081252 405777  1   1442346826
2081252 805572  1   1441286115
732722  1266442 1   1446745768
687093  2651366 1   1445373507
```

now by simple grouping this data on 'item_id' and 'user_id' such as:

```
grouped = interactions_df.groupby(['item_id', 'user_id']).count()
print(grouped)
```

I got this result:

```
item_id user_id interaction_type    created_at
405777   2690450        1   1
         2081252        1   1    
805572   2081252        1   1 
1180447  2690450        1   1 
1266442  732722         1   1 
1803133  2690450        1   1
2651366  687093         1   1
2668706  1974005        1   1
```

Now what I need is to store my data in a csv file, but in this format

```
item_id user_id 
405777   2690450, 2081252            
805572   2081252        
1180447  2690450         
1266442  732722          
1803133  2690450        
2651366  687093         
2668706  1974005
```

if there is multiple users for single item then I need it in a comma separated list and just these 2 columns, no other information or counts.

How can I achieve this? Please suggest.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can first [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) to remove Multiindex. Then [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) again and [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) `join` (if column `user_id` is numeric, you need cast `int` to `string` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html)) and last write [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html):

```
grouped = interactions_df.groupby(['item_id', 'user_id'], as_index=False).count()
print(grouped)
   item_id  user_id  interaction_type  created_at
0   405777  2081252                 1           1
1   405777  2690450                 1           1
2   805572  2081252                 1           1
3  1180447  2690450                 1           1
4  1266442   732722                 1           1
5  1803133  2690450                 1           1
6  2651366   687093                 1           1
7  2668706  1974005                 1           1

df = grouped.groupby('item_id')['user_id'].apply(lambda x: ", ".join(x.astype(str)))
                                          .reset_index()
print df

   item_id           user_id
0   405777  2081252, 2690450
1   805572           2081252
2  1180447           2690450
3  1266442            732722
4  1803133           2690450
5  2651366            687093
6  2668706           1974005

df.to_csv('file', index=False)
```

Another little crazy solution with [`get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html):

```
grouped = interactions_df.groupby(['item_id', 'user_id']).count()

print grouped.index.get_level_values('user_id').to_series()
             .groupby(grouped.index.get_level_values('item_id'))
             .apply(lambda x: ", ".join(x.astype(str)))
             .reset_index(name='user_id')

   item_id           user_id
0   405777  2081252, 2690450
1   805572           2081252
2  1180447           2690450
3  1266442            732722
4  1803133           2690450
5  2651366            687093
6  2668706           1974005
```

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion worked perfectly fine for my data. But could you explain me a bit, how it works?

Comment: how reset_index() worked?  and grouped.groupby('item_id')['user_id'] part

Comment: How reset works is better explain in docs [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#reset-the-index). And `apply` is aggregating data with some function. Obvious it is `sum` or `mean`, but you can use some functions with parameters. Then use anonymous function `lambda`. I think the best explained `groupby` is [here](http://wesmckinney.com/blog/groupby-fu-improvements-in-grouping-and-aggregating-data-in-pandas/).

Comment: Btw, I think `pandas` documentation is very nice, if starts you can check [cookbook](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/cookbook.html). Thank you again and nice day. Good luck!